# How do Android Launchers start Chrome in Full Screen (WebApp) mode?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I've got a sticky situation.  I'm developing a kiosk-style tablet application on JellyBean, and we're stuck with JellyBean.

We don't install a standard launcher on our Android tablets, and instead supply our own Home Screen/Launcher app, so that our application starts on system startup.

We were using a WebView for our GUI app.  The WebView that comes with JellyBean is buggy and deficient in many ways, so our app doesn't work correctly in the WebView.

However, Chrome runs our app perfectly, so we want to switch to using Chrome, which we would launch from our own Home Screen application on startup.

We need to start it in full-screen mode, just like Launchers do when they launch any app/URL via a link that was placed on the Desktop.

I can't for the life of me find out how launchers pull this off.

I've tried adding --app="xxx", and/or --start-fullscreen to the /data/local/chrome-command-line file, but all to no avail.  The additions options show up on the "chrome://version" screen in Chrome, but they have no effect.

Does anyone have any clue how they manage to launch Chrome in full-screen mode?

These tablets are all rooted tablets, completely under our own control, so no solution is out of bounds.

Thanks for any help!